# what would be the FOL of this: "Happy people have exciting lives"

Tags: first-order-logic

I am confused whether I should use Existential Quantifier or not.

i only use existential quantifier on cases with "some", so how should I solve this one?

Comment: Can you define predicates for "is happy" and "has an exciting life"?

Comment: $H$: Happy. $E$: Exciting life. 
$$
H \Rightarrow E
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\forall x (Hx \rightarrow EL x)$ where $H$ denotes the predicate 'is happy' and $EL$ denotes the predicate 'has an exiting life'.

Comment: why use universal quantifier? "it didnt say all happy people have exciting lives"